# How to use logical "and" operator in linq

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work ? It returns an empty list.
My http request looks like this: `https://localhost:44313/api/movies/7/9`
And I have a movie with a rating =8 in the database.

```
 [HttpGet("{Start}/{End}")]
 public IEnumerable<Movie> GetReport(int start, int end)
 {
     return _context.Movies
         .Where(m => (m.Rating >= start) && (m.Rating <= end))
         .OrderBy(x => x.YearRelease)
         .ToList();
 }
```

Comment: it looks fine, are you sure the `and` is the problem? If you remove one or the other condition, you get a non-empty list? Maybe your start and end values are 0 if the binding is not working?

Comment: Have you debugged it to ensure that `start` and `end` are what you expect them to be?  They are capitalized in your route template, but not in the parameters list...

Comment: The default value of ints are 0, might be that `start` and `end` contains 0 and is returning an empty enumerable as suggested by @Amy

Comment: Yeap. Solved the problem . Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The binding is the problem

assuming your controller is named `MoviesController`, maybe try

```
 [HttpGet("{start}/{end}")]
 public IEnumerable<Movie> GetReport([FromUri]int start, [FromUri]int end)
 {
     return _context.Movies
         .Where(m => (m.Rating >= start) && (m.Rating <= end))
         .OrderBy(x => x.YearRelease)
         .ToList();
 }
```

Comment: I tried at first with [fromUri ] but it didn`t import . I don`t know why . But the capitalized letter from my route were the problem .

Comment: @Andrada the route parameters must *exactly* match the functions parameter names unless you specifically tell it otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Debug it.  I would guess that the function parameter variables aren't populating properly so it's looking for 0<=rating<=0.  Could be case sensitivity of the tag maybe?

Comment: Yes you are right . I was trying to find out what `s wrong with and operator but now I see that my parameters are 0. Why is that ?

Comment: Try making them lowercase in the attribute
 [HttpGet("{start}/{end}")]

Comment: Yeap. Solved the problem . Thank you